# How to specify a wildcard path for jar libraries for a java command line application?

Tags: java

I'm writing a command line utility to extract Adobe Form Data from PDF's

This command line fails.

```
java -classpath jars/*.jar:. extractpdfformdata.ExtractPDFFormData --pdf csmu-asfm.pdf
```

where as this works.

```
java -classpath jars/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar:. extractpdfformdata.ExtractPDFFormData --pdf csmu-asfm.pdf
```

What is the correct way to pass in wildcard paths for jar libraries to java?

Comment: Just put `jars/*:.`

Comment: Thanks. Can you write that up as an answer. Why does jars/*.jar fail?

Comment: It fails because the "*" here is not a Unix wildcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to use simply `jars/*`.  Classpath wildcards in the Oracle JRE represent a list of `.jar` files, and not part of the file name.  Here's a quote from the documentation:

> Class path entries can contain the base name wildcard character `(*)`,
>   which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all of the
>   files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example,
>   the class path entry `mydir/*` specifies all JAR files in the directory
>   named `mydir`. A class path entry consisting of `*` expands to a list of
>   all the jar files in the current directory. Files are considered
>   regardless of whether they are hidden (have names beginning with '.').

Reference: *Class Path Wild Cards* at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: See also [*Adding all JARs in a folder to the classpath*](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/3720/the-classpath/12854/adding-all-jars-in-a-folder-to-the-classpath#t=201611192355232530489).